# How to pass connection from my java swing application to Crystal Reports XI?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have this code which I use on my swing application:

```
    ReportClientDocument rpt =  new ReportClientDocument();
    rpt.open(reportPath+"APVendorList.rpt", 0);
    rpt.getReportSource();


    ReportViewerBean viewer = new ReportViewerBean();
    viewer.init(new String[0], null, null, null);
    //viewer.setHasGroupTree(false);
    viewer.setReportSource(rpt.getReportSource());
```

The problem is that whenever I try to load the report using jframe, It always ask for login credentials:

```
Database Logon:
Server Name: Localhost
Database Name: <blank and cannot be edited>
User ID:
Password:
```

Is there a way to not type in those info eveytime I view the report? Or I could just pass java.sql.Connection to it? Also it seems like it doesnt know which database to connect to. Please help.

Comment: *"How to pass connection from my java swing application to Crystal Reports XI?"*  Probably the same way you'd do it from the command line.  What does Swing have to with this?

Comment: Oops! sorry for the misleading title. I guess it should be, "How to pass connection from my java swing application to my crystal report"?

Comment: The same comments apply to the suggested altered title.  Note also it is Java & Swing, not java & swing.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. I hope your comments could answer my problem. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the property values, something like this:

```
ReportClientDocument clientDoc = new ReportClientDocument();
....
DatabaseController dbController=clientDoc.getDatabaseController();
IConnectionInfo ConnInfo = dbController.getConnectionInfos(null).getConnectionInfo(0);
com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.PropertyBag boPropertyBag1 = new com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.PropertyBag();
// Set the properties for the connection
boPropertyBag1.put("JDBC Connection String", connString);
boPropertyBag1.put("Database Class Name", dbClassName);
boPropertyBag1.put("Connection URL", connString);
boPropertyBag1.put("Server", serverHost);
....
// Assign the properties to the connection info
ConnInfo.setAttributes(boPropertyBag1);
// Set the DB Username and Pwd
ConnInfo.setUserName(usrName);
ConnInfo.setPassword(pwd);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that code and it worked, once. After the first run I got an error message:

 com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKServerException: There is no server specified.---- Error code:-2147217390 Error code name:serverNotFound

Btw after checking the class I got a simple solution and it actually worked. 

    ReportClientDocument rpt =  new ReportClientDocument();
    rpt.open(reportPath+"Contact.rpt", 0);
    rpt.getDatabaseController().logon("username", "password");

is this right? I dont know the consequence of that simple code.